# MySQL Table with a ? at the end

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'names?' that I want to change to 'names'.

Ultimately I'm going to dump the table, but is there a way to change it?
Every time I attempt to either dump or change it, I get a SQL syntax error.

```
mysql> rename table 'names?' TO names;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''names?' TO names' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks instead of apostrophes:

```
rename table `names?` TO names;
```

Comment: You're a beautiful person. I'm so used to bash that I didn't think of backticks. Had tried single and double quotes to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
rename table `names?` TO `names`;
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution to above problem can be in two ways:-

1. try using ALTER command rather than rename command.
2. The error it is showing can be sometimes related to the syntax that you are using is not for the version of mysql you are using. Try searching for the exact query for your mysql version.